# Promise not waiting on one another

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

So my understanding of promises lead me to believe that my other promises would run one after another in my then chain but I'm doing something wrong here.

The code I'm using currently is as follows

```
const mainPromise = () => Promise.resolve(
    console.log('spinner spinning...')
    ...spinner code.... //this is omitted code
);

const getData = () => Promise.resolve(
    someObj.getProducts('data.json')
);

const updateProduct = () => Promise.resolve(
    setTimeout(()=>{
        someObj.updateProductHTML()
    }, 0)
);

const updateDom = () => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        someObj.updateDOM()
    }, 0)
};
```

and my promise chain

```
mainPromise()
    .then(getData)
    .then(updateProduct)
    .then(updateDom)
;
```

They seem to be initially running in order but the Ajax call I have in getProducts also has a for loop worker to build my array of objects and is finishing after all my .thens run.

I am attempting to at least have my data call and worker finish before updateProduct and updateDOM runs

--- UPDATE ---

ok so with the revised promises set up as such as per suggestions in the comments and Samanime's answer

```
 const mainPromise = () => Promise.resolve(
    console.log('spinner spinning...')
);

const getData = () => new Promise( resolve => {
    console.log('getData');
        someObj.getProducts('data.json');
        resolve();
    }
);

const updateProduct = () => new Promise( resolve =>{
   console.log('updateProduct');
   someObj.updateProductHTML();
   resolve();
});

//execute promise chain

mainPromise()
    .then(getData)
    .then(updateProduct)
    .then(page.updateDOM)
;
```

I updated the promises to not immediately resolve and am attempting to call resolve after I call my functions ( although I'm uneasy as to if resolve will be called before or after these functions ).

Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same behavior. I've added console  logs to my functions as well as my promises and I'm getting this list back

```
   log.spinner spinning
   log.getData
   log.updateProduct
   log.A log from the function updateProduct calls
   log.48 product objects created (for loop worker in my getProducts   function)
   log.Data retrieved and assigned
   the last two logs would ideally be called after getData
```

None of the calls or functions outside of the ones provided are return promises, I'm working on legacy code and I'm moving away from the setTimeout trick as well as my results weren't consistent.

--UPDATE 2 --

The problem I'm having is known as Forking/Splitting. I just need to figure out chaining specifically to fix my issue.

-- FINAL --

this is what I ended up working out

```
 // execute promise chain

mainPromise()
    .then(getData);

//the timeout is a little hack to ensure the sequence is kept
mainPromise()
    .then(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            myObj.updateProductHTML();
            myObj.updateDOM();
        }, 0);

    });
```

apparently `.then(foo).then(bar)` just runs foo and bar at the same time

seems to be working ok right but I feel like somethings not right with it still.

Comment: Try returning the Promise.resolve(...)

Comment: The format he is using is returning the resolve.

Comment: Why do you (think you) need those `Promise.resolve` calls? Don't the spinner, `getProducts` and update methods return promises by themselves?

Comment: You should instead use `new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {...});`. This will run the function asynchronously. `resolve()` will resolve, and `reject()` will reject.

Comment: I just tried it and I believe you are right. Wasn't sure if he had to explicitly add the return or not.

Comment: @MikeCheel It's known as a *concise body* whose result is implicitly returned

Comment: Do I not need the resolves? I suppose the code originally did the same thing it's doing now without them.

Comment: @Bergi I know I haven't programming in Js for a few months and that was what first came to mind. Having looked closer, if his Promise.resolves meed to return the promises they are calling and while the code could definitely improved that should make it work.

Comment: `Promise.resolve()` immediately resolves value passed as parameter

Comment: @RobertBrush You need to return a thenable (i.e. a promise) to the calling promise, in this case Promise.Resolve. Bergi is correct though that if you are returning promises inside of the Promise.resolve calls the Promise.resolve calls are moot.

Comment: @RobertBrush What is "spinner code"?

Comment: @RobertBrush Updated `javascript` calls `resolve()` immediately. What does `page.getProducts('data.json');` and `page.updateProductHTML();` return, respectively? Do both calls return a `Promise`?

Comment: @RobertBrush show us the code of your spinner, `getProducts`, `updateProductHTML` and `updateDOM` methods. If they are asynchronous, *they* need to either take a callback or return a promise.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's because `Promise.resolve()` doesn't do quite what you think it does.

`Promise.resolve()` creates a new Promise and resolves it immediately using the **value** of what it's given. Things like `setTimeout` return their id (an integer) immediately, so they aren't doing what you want. Your `getProducts()` is probably an async call, so it may be returning `null` or something as well (if it's returning a `Promise` or returns the value synchronously, then it's fine).

You're better off writing a normal Promise and calling `resolve()` at the appropriate time.

```
const mainPromise = () => Promise.resolve(
    console.log('spinner spinning...')
    ...spinner code....
);

// Assuming it's already returning a Promise or synchronous response. If it isn't, then deal with it like the setTimeout ones below.
const getData = () => someObj.getProducts('data.json')

const updateProduct = () => new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        someObj.updateProductHTML();
        resolve();
    }, 0)
});

// You don't NEED to in your example since it's at the end of the chain, but you probably want to wrap this too in case you add to the chain.
const updateDom = () => new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        someObj.updateDOM();
        resolve();
    }, 0)
});
```

Comment: What does `mainPromise()` return? Should `Promise` constructor be substituted for `Promise.resolve()` at `mainPromise` as well?

Comment: `mainPromise()` returns a `Promise`, which can then be subsequently chained. The **value** it returns is null, but that's okay.

Comment: What is purpose of using `Promise.resolve()` at `mainPromise`? Where "  console.log('spinner spinning...')
    ...spinner code.... //this is omitted code" are parameters?

Comment: It needs to return a `Promise` in some way to be able further chain off of it. You can use `Promise.resolve()` or `new Promise()`. `Promise.resolve()` is just a bit shorter. For chaining with another function where the next step doesn't care about a value from the previous, we don't care what goes on inside, so `Promise.resolve()` is a bit shorter, which is why it's used.